# Design pattern for fragments in android

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, fragment

I am reading a book and it says like this 
"Right now, fragments are very new, so there are few well-established
patterns to follow"

But I do not know where to read more about the design patterns for fragments at all.

I want to make an application with a lot of different screens and the app should be available for a tablet and for a phone, so the fragments will help me a lot here. But as I said this is big one and I am about to start designing it. So I really need good design. And before I start I want to see some design patterns guidelines for fragments in android.

I there something like best practices or something ?
I read a lot about fragments their usage and all those stuff, but I didn't find some well established design pattern for making app for phones and tablets.

I really need advanced chapter about this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably read this but just in case, the [Android Reference Document on Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) quite nicely explains how to separate your UI and the Example right at the bottom of the page shows a reasonable way of how a UI using fragments can include more or less fragments given a change in orientation.

Comment: I read that and also http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html this is very useful especially the part fragments for all. But

Comment: I do not how to google it, I could find anything that I was looking for. It is like there is lack of information about this